# Put one local file into multiple HDFS directories

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, cloudera

I am writing a sanity tests for CDH 5.3 cluster installs.  We have a test case that will create a Hive table on a directory with 1000 partitions and then query random partitions.  Originally done with a series of for loops, it took hours to do:

hadoop fs -mkdir -p /hdfs/directory/partition{1...1000}

then:

hadoop fs -put /path/to/local/file /hdfs/directory/partitionX

Passing one local file to multiple directories just throws an error, but using a for loop takes hours to complete.  -copyFromLocal throws a similar error to -put.  Also, -put to the first directory and copied with a for loop takes quite a bit of time as well.

Any ideas on how to copy one file to many directories in the quickest and most efficient way possible?

Comment: As it sounds like you want to copy the same file to multiple locations you might get better performance by doing a `put` and then using `cp` http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.19.1/hdfs_shell.html#cp to move to the other HDFS directories.

Comment: `cp` might not help as the data has to go via the HDFS client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to speed up the copy, some kind of parallelism is needed. It would be easy to run a multi-thread program to submit dozens of hdfs copy command a time in java.

With shell script, you may do something like:

```
m=10
for (( i = 0; i < 100; i++ )); do
   sh hdfs_cp_script partition$(($i*$m + 1)) & sh hdfs_cp_script partition$(($i*$m + 2) & ... & sh hdfs_cp_script partition$(($i*$m + 10))
done
```

to submit multiple (10) commands a time for a loop of 100.

Comment: That bash script almost worked like a charm for our purposes but it forgets to to anything with a 0 (i.e. 10, 20, 30...170, 180, 190)

Comment: That's weird. Looking at a testing script:m=4; for (( i = 0; i < 6; i++ )); do echo $(($i*$m + 1)); echo $(($i*$m + 2));  echo $(($i*$m + 3)) ;  done ;  The result does include some 0s : 1 2 3 5 6 7 9 10 11 13 14 15 17 18 19 21 22 23

Comment: This solves the problem because each hdfs/hadoop -fs job starts a new job, and each is performed seriatim (one after the other, in series). Each is small-ish, but you need them parallel.

Comment: @Paul H. If my Hive table is partitioned on some date column, how to do the same with using above script? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A faster way to achieve this would be to write a Java application that uses the [Hadoop FileSystem API](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html) to write the file into the various HDFS directories.

Comment: could you please show some code or script to do that. will be really helpful :-)